# Weak convergence of Gibbs measures with converging energy functions

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, large-deviations

Let $H$ be a continuous   energy function defined on   a compact subset  $A\subset \mathbf{R}^n$
and let   $Q$ be a fixed probability measure on $A$.
For each $\theta>0$, define the probability measure $P_\theta$ on $A$ by
$$\frac{dP_\theta}{dQ}(x)  = \frac{\exp{(-H(x)/\theta)}}{\int \exp{(-H(x)/\theta)}dQ(x)}.$$
Then under certain regularity conditions of $H$,  [Chii-Ruey Hwang's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-8/issue-6/Laplaces-Method-Revisited-Weak-Convergence-of-Probability-Measures/10.1214/aop/1176994579.full)
shows that
the measures $(P_\theta)_{\theta>0}$ converges weakly to a probability measure supported on the minimal set
$$N = \{x\in A | H(x) = \min_{y\in A} H(y) \}. $$

Now suppose that I have a sequence of continuous and bounded functions  $(H_\theta)_{\theta>0}$ converges uniformly to $H$ on $A$.
I was wondering whether the same weak convergence result still holds for the following Gibbs measures:
$$\frac{dP_\theta}{dQ}(x)  = \frac{\exp{(-H_\theta(x)/\theta)}}{\int \exp{(-H_\theta(x)/\theta)}dQ(x)}.$$
Has  such a problem been studied in the literature (say the large derivation theory)? If so, could you provide me a reference for it?